# One half of jQuery script works, other doesn't

Tags: jquery, magento

For the past view day's I've been smashing my head into the wall on this problem I'm having.
I've got a page which you could consider a product finder: see it here:
http://media-surfer.nl/test/

I want to include this page into a mangeto store that I run:
http://ongedierteproducten.nl/bieb

I know Magento uses prototype and scriptaculous so I used jQuery.noConflict();
While this enabled the functionality for the thumbs, the sorting menu still doesn't function.

I would be over the moon if anyone could give me a pointer.

Kind regards,
Jason.

jQuery in magento page:

```
<!-- collapse expand jquery -->
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        jQuery(".inhoud").hide();
        jQuery(".show_hide").show();

    jQuery(document).on('click','.show_hide', function(event) { 

        jQuery(".inhoud").parent().animate({
            width: '160'
          }, 500, function() {
            // Animation complete.
          });


        var $inhoud = jQuery(this).next(".inhoud");

        if($inhoud.hasClass("active")) 
        {
            jQuery(this).parent().animate({
                width: '160'
              }, 500, function() {
                // Animation complete.
              });
            $inhoud.removeClass("active");
            jQuery("div.inhoud").hide();
        } else {
            jQuery(this).parent().animate({
                width: '769'
              }, 500, function() {
                // Animation complete.
              });

            $inhoud.addClass("active");
            jQuery(this).next("div.inhoud").show();
        }

    });

});
```

```
<!-- filter plugin -->
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var _filterPortfolio = jQuery('#portfolio').filterPortfolio({
            initFilter: '#all', 
            itemUL: '#itemUL',
            filterButtons: [ 
                {'link': '#all', 'dom': 'li'}, 
                {'link': '#kruipt', 'dom': 'li.kruipt'}, 
                {'link': '#vliegt', 'dom': 'li.vliegt'}, 
                {'link': '#staart', 'dom': 'li.staart'} 
            ], 

            orderReverse: true,
            sortOption: {
                adjustHeight: 'auto',
                easeIn: 'fadeIn',
                easeOut: 'fadeOut'
            }
        });         

        jQuery("select#easeInType").change(selChange);  
        jQuery("select#easeOutType").change(selChange);             
        function selChange(){
            var _easeIn = jQuery('select#easeInType').val();
            var _easeOut = jQuery('select#easeOutType').val();              
            _filterPortfolio.updateAnimation(_easeIn, _easeOut);
            jQuery('#selections').hide();
        }

        jQuery('#toggleImg').on('click', function(event){
            jQuery('#selections').toggle();
        })                      


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your jQuery code each in an [anonymous function](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-anonymous-function-calls) like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
;(function($){
    // all jQuery code:
    $(document).ready(function(){
    // your code
    });
})(jQuery);
```

You should put all of your js code in .js files, rather than putting them inline, if it is possible.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :)
So the idea is to put all the js used in a single file and include that from the page?

Comment: No problem :) I am not sure what you are asking? It is always better to include a .js file than writing all your js code inside the html file of course.
The point rather is to use anonymous functions to use your jQuery code if you have library conflicts.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, should I only paste the inline code within this function or also all the other files that are included for operation?

Thanks again :)